# how can i see data in mdf file

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, mdf, ldf

i have asp.net application. it has App_Data folder. this folder contain mdf and ldf file.
how can i see data within these file. i want to see table structure.

Comment: See [How to: Attach a Database (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using SQL Server Management Studio Express you can attach that file.

[How to attach a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx)

However, if you are viewing that in a project in Visual Studio, you can see that in the server explorer.

Also, [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1369611.aspx) is a similar question on the asp.net forums.