# How to change data inside an mdf file in localdb

Tags: localdb, mdf

My question is similar to this, but I don't have a "real" Server only localdb from Microsoft SQL-Server Express:

[how can i see data in mdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711152/how-can-i-see-data-in-mdf-file/1711189)

I have a (closed) tool I need to export data from to import it with groovy into a web application. The instructions said to download "Microsoft SQL-Server Express 2012 LocalDB". I installed it and everything works fine, I was never asked to enter a DB Name, Username or Password.

Now I have to change some data inside the mdf file but I have no idea how, I never worked with any Microsoft SQL Products. Basically a standard sql console would be enough for me.

In the linked question it was suggested to link the file in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, however I am asked for a server name and can't connect to localhost.

Can I connect the Management studio to the localdb? Or is there any way to execute simple sql commands on the mdf file or anything else I can do?

Comment: why don't you download mssql express, which is a full-but-size-limited version of mssql, and then you can attach your file and use it like any other file.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. Like I said, I never worked with any Microsoft SQL Servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marc B was right:

Install both "Microsoft SQL-Server Express 2012" and the tools, attach the file, and you can execute any SQL commands inside the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Overall I hope I never have to use this again :)